# arm-none-eabi linker issues when trying to compile C++ on Tiva Launchpad

Tags: c++, c, embedded, cortex-m

I've been working on a rather large-scoped project ([project](https://github.com/cmonr/Embedded-Software/tree/master/TI/tm4c123gh6pm/C%2B%2B%20Obj%20Uart) in reference) for the Tiva Launchpad (ARM Cortex M4) in Arch Linux (x64), and have seem to run into a snag.

The project is using both C and C++, and have been doing alright until now. The snag started when I started working on the interface between objects and the system's interrupts. The output is fairly noisy, so here's the pastebin link: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BBey7NxY). I'm sure that I'm just doing something silly in the Makefile, or not, but just don't know it.

I've never seen anything like this (no, it's not related to the VFP registers or newlib, I think). I'm not sure how to even approach something like this, and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I looked at the pastbin post. It is difficult read the code, do want update the post with a sub sections of code.

Comment: I ended up figuring out what the issue was. It turns out somewhere deep in my code I was using the `new` operator, and shenanegans were happening.

Lesson learnt.